does pool deck need beams under it?
Of course if you ask someone, you're going to get lots of opinions. I did the deck design at Menards & Lowe's. Both show using beams. A contractor said he doesn't use them.
The deck measures 16' x 16' and the corners both narrow down to 7ft.


how do they expect that span to be supported?

It's possible for joists to span 16', depending on species, spacing, and joist height, neither of which is known (pic is so tiny I can't see if that info is included).  https://www.decksdirect.com/media/wysiwyg/JRB/deck-joist-span-chart-decksdirect.png

Beams holding decks/floors up are probably the cheapest and easiest to do.  With enough posts, probably do not need beams, but a lot of posts.  We need to know what the contractor expects to use instead of beams.

@crip659 I would assume rim joists—but without a framing plan, who knows?

It would be nice to confirm if the contractor does not use beams or does not use those designs.
